# Get a contour (x,y) coordinates of a shape in an image with python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

I need to get a matrix with the coordinates (x,y) of the contour of the following image with python.

[image]

I try it with opencv canny detector and find contours but I get a lot of contours and I don't know how to get the one I want.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
#from skimage import measure, feature, io
#from skimage import img_as_ubyte

x1 = 330
xf = 690
y1 = 0
yf = 400

img = cv2.imread('test.tif')
img = img[y1:yf, x1:xf]
edge = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edge, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

[image]

I just need an array with the (x,y) coordinates of the contour. I think it is in the contours output of `cv2.findContours()` but I don't find the contour that I want…

I also tried with the `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` function :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.tif', 0) # read image
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] # threshold image
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 15)  # remove noise

# skeletonize 
size = np.size(img)  # get number of pixels
skel = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8) # create an array of zeros with the same shape as the image and 256 gray levels

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3)) # create a structurant element (cross)
done = False

while(not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(img, element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded, element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(img, temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel, temp)
    img = eroded.copy()
    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
    if zeros == size:
        done = True

cs = plt.contour(skel, 1)
p = cs.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
v = p.vertices
x = v[:, 0]
y = v[:, 1]
```

[image]

But I just have closed contours and not the open contour which is going from the left to the right of the image.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'contour'? What is your expected output? Be specific.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @barny. By contour I mean a line going from left to right and passing through the points where intensity gradient is maximal. And i need the the (x,y) coordinates of this line in a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost found the answer to your question. First of all, there is a difference between **edge detection** and **contour detection**. Fundamentally, edge detection results in what you call (improperly) "open contour" (i.e. edge) and contour detection results in what you call "closed contour" (i.e. contour).

The **Canny edge detection** is a popular edge detection algorithm. Since you want to detect the edge in the form of an array with the (x,y) coordinates going from the left to the right of the image, the Canny edge detection is a good idea.

The answer is `edge` which is not in the wanted format.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.tif')
edge = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

ans = []
for y in range(0, edge.shape[0]):
    for x in range(0, edge.shape[1]):
        if edge[y, x] != 0:
            ans = ans + [[x, y]]
ans = np.array(ans)

print(ans.shape)
print(ans[0:10, :])
```

The array `ans` (shape equal to `(n, 2)`) stores the (x, y)-coordinate of the `n` pixels which compose the detected edge. This is the result you are looking for.

Here is an image where I have plotted in white these `n` pixels:

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanations baptiste, that's exactly what I wan't !!