# How do you get the coordinates of the boundaries of each closed area?

Tags: python, autocad

I have a list of coordinates of each line that forms such a drawing:

[image: DRAWING]

The task is to get the coordinates of all boundaries of closed objects. There are 15 closed objects in total. How can this be realized in autocad? Or using python.

The input data is too large, so I will show the format of this data - coordinates_list = [[x, y, z, x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3] etc.].

I tried to use the _-BOUNDARY command in autocad, but this command doesn't work because it doesn't allow you to read coordinates.

In python I tried to use DFS algorithm, but it finds always less number of objects

Comment: you can use opencv for this

Comment: @TinoD, not familiar with such a library. Can you help me write code with a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: I don't want to do your work for you. This is not the logic of Stackoverflow questions. There are a lot of questions here with the same goal: find (X, Y) coordinates from a contour. Check this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593165/get-a-contour-x-y-coordinates-of-a-shape-in-an-image-with-python. After you check it, and you feel that you don't understand something/ can't get something to work, come back with a reproducible question and we can help you further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CaptainTrunky pointed out, in this case you need to use cycle_basic from the networkx library. I didn't get the desired result right away, because the area boundaries are displayed in a non-closed form. And to make them appear correctly, you need to duplicate the first point in the end:

```
coordinates = [(x1, y2, x2, y2), (x2, y2, x3, y4), etc.].

point_lists = [[pair for pair in zip(line[::2],line[1::2])] for line in coordinates]
edges = [segment for point_list in point_lists for segment in zip(point_list[::-1], point_list[1:])]
G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)

# cycle_basis
cycle_basis = nx.cycle_basis(G)
print("cycle_basis: =", len(cycle_basis)))
for cycle in cycle_basis:
    cycle.append(cycle[0])
    print(cycle)
```

Comment: Cool finding! I'm really glad that my suggestions steered you in the right way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that the thing you need is called [cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis). You could try using [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) python package to build cycle basis, see the [example](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.cycle_basis.html). Algorithmically speaking, it works roughly in the following way:

1. Build a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree). There would be some edges that are missing from a tree
2. Iterate over each missing edge and build a cycle that adds it to a tree. Each such cycle would be a part of cycle basis

I'm not sure about the problem you are solving, e.g. do you need a basis or a minimal basis or a full enumeration of all cycles in a graph, but most likely you will find a solution using the same networkx library

Comment: So you're suggesting I use a chordless loop search? Personally, I have not been able to implement it. If you know how to do it, please send the code with a minimally reproducible example

Comment: @bobby-lith Just adopt an example from here, you don't really need to implement it yourself - https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.cycle_basis.html

Comment: I have tried all available methods in networkx, but they all gave wrong results. The number of closed areas in the drawing is 15, and none of the methods showed this number.

`cycle_basis: 8
simple_cycles: 34
find_cycle: 22   
minimum_cycle_basis: 8
chordless_cycles: 11
girth: 4
recursive_simple_cycles: 0`

Comment: @BobbyLith I think that (at least in theory) chordless_cycles is exactly the thing you need. Could you visually check what's wrong with the output? Could you please prepare a CSV file that describes your graph (just a list of edges between nodes)? I would like to play around it next few days.

Comment: How can I send you a CSV? Can we open a discussion?

Comment: The essence of a chordless loop is not to use one edge twice. But we need to use the same edge more than once in order to find all the figures in the closure of which this edge takes part